# Process.Start starts to return null after some random number of calls

Tags: vb.net

When I initially start my IDE and run the WinForm in debug mode, I do not get any error.

But after a couple of debug runs, `myProcess.WaitForExit()` out of nowhere throws 
an `NullReferenceException`.

```
   REM This function with the help of the command line just the given command can be executed on CMD/DOSBox or not
    Function CanBeExecuted(ByVal command As String) As Boolean

        Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
        ProcessProperties.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT") + "\SYSTEM32\where" 'This utility is generally used to find the location of the script or executable
        ProcessProperties.Arguments = command
        ProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        ProcessProperties.CreateNoWindow = True
        Dim myProcess = Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
        myProcess.WaitForExit()

        REM So if the process returns 0, it means that the command is recognized by Windows
        REM Else it is not

        If myProcess.ExitCode = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

Comment: Why do you start the process twice?

Comment: I refactored the code to remove it later..Thanks for the info...I was actually tired with that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start` might fail and then return `null` instead of a valid `Process` object. This is the case here.

Why does it work at first and then fail?

Probably because your main process uses up all process handles it is allowed to use. The `Process` objects get cleaned up by GC, but there might be much time between GC cycles, so you still might run into the situation, that all your process handles are used up and hence the code fails to allocate more. Even though you don't actually use the old ones anymore.

If this is the case, you should be able to solve the issue by explicitly calling the `Dispose` method on the `Process` object by calling

```
myProcess.Dispose()
```